# I cannot connect between node.js and oracle

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, oracle, database-connection

I want to connect to oracle on different server with Node.js. I'm getting the ***"Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804"*** error. Although I did a lot of research, I could not reach a positive result. I think a few files are missing. But I don't know what files are missing. What is your suggestion as a solution?

```js
const oracledb = require('oracledb')
oracledb.getConnection({
    user: 'myUser',
    password: 'myPass',
    connectString: '192.168.1.162/PRVS'
},
    function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
            return;
        }
        else {
            connection.execute(
                'SELECT * from myTable',
                [12],
                {
                    maxRows: 1
                },
                function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err.message)
                        doRelease(connection)
                        return;
                    }
                    console.log(results.rows)
                    doRelease(connection)
                }
            )
        }
        connection.close(
            function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err.message);
                }
            }
        )
    }
)
```

Comment: Update your post with details about what you have installed, such as the Oracle DB version, the Oracle client library version, and whether you have different versions of Oracle software installed on the same machine.  If you are using Oracle Instant Client, then don't set the ORACLE_HOME environment variable.

Comment: Side note: you will find the async/await style of coding much easier to follow, debug, and get correct.  The callback style you use gets complex and hard to follow. All the current node-oracledb [examples](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/tree/master/examples) use async/await, as does the [documentation](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'm starting to try. I have one more problem.I'm developing in the .Net environment I get a "ORA-00980: synonym translation is no longer valid" error when querying select.

Comment: Open a new question for that issue.