# Error ORA-01804-Connecting the Oracle DB using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, oracle, oracleclient

I was tring to connect the oracle using NodeJs , Getting an  Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01804at OracleDb.createPool

Action Taken: (Added in env variable)

- Added ORACLE_HOME = C:\instantclient
- Added LD_LIBRARY_PATH = C:\instantclient\sdk\lib

*for my project need a instant client 18 or 19 version so that i have added in env*

still no use , kindly help me out

*Expected result :*

Connected successfully , able to access oracle DB

Comment: Don't use the `mysql` tag for Oracle questions.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23063444/421195, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65841338 or here: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/76

Comment: okay let me check

Comment: @Barmar  i have only this folder which is 
- C:\app\naveen\product\18.0.0\oradata\XE
which once is ORACLE_HOME  & LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: @naveenAspiresys What does that have to do with using an incorrect tag?

Comment: @Barmar  can you pls help me to find the correct path

Comment: I've never used Oracle, so I don't know.

Comment: Since you have Oracle XE installed, remove Instant Client to stop the library clash you are experiencing.  XE has all the libraries that node-oracledb needs. Also, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is typically a Linux environment variable.  You are on Windows.  Unset it.  You will also probably want to unset ORACLE_HOME if you have explicitly set that.  You want the Oracle environment to be set to use XE.